# "shutdown" vs "reboot" on Debian

Tags: linux, debian

A friend has lectured me I should use `shutdown ..` rather available `reboot` command available in Debian systems.

Is this reasonable and supported by facts rather than by fashion of making UNIX/Linux commands cryptic? I mean if `reboot` is there provided by Debian developers, shouldn't it stands to reason it's perfectly OK to use it?

Please advise.

Comment: Did he give you a reason?

Comment: @vidarlo Except "you should use this and that flag to shutdown", no.

Comment: Use whatever you're comfortable with. Both seem to perform a clean reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First things first, what these commands actually do:**

- Both commands are a symbolic link to `systemctl`, the command line utility of `systemd`.
- You can simply verify this by executing `ls -la /usr/sbin/shutdown` and `ls -la /usr/sbin/reboot`
- Thus, the commands are interpreted by `systemd`, which then decides the action to perform (among other tasks).
- `systemd` is the init system that Debian uses and simply put, responsible for starting and stopping services, including invoking a shutdown and reboot
- Shortly, both commands end up calling a specific `systemd` target, which in the end executes a system call. That's what defines what actually is happening.

Knowing this, both commands can lead to the very same targets and thus the very same kernel calls, doing the very same action. That fully depends on the command line options you use on these commands.

**What does this mean for common cases?**

- Simple reboots are accomplished with `shutdown -r` and `reboot`. They lead to the same systemd target and therefore are doing exactly the same.
- Shutdowns are accomplished with `shutdown -h now` or `shutdown -P now`. You cannot accomplish a shutdown with the `reboot` command to my knowledge, as the `--poweroff` switch is simply ignored when it is invoked through the `reboot` command

**So, should you avoid the `reboot` command**?

As shown both do their task. Depending on whether you want a shutdown or reboot, you use one of these commands with the appropriate options. There is no particular reason to specifically avoid the `reboot` command, as, in case of rebooting it does the very same thing as `shutdown -r`.

**Source and more in depth description**

You can read a more in-detailed description in ["What is the difference between these commands for bringing down a Linux server?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195898/what-is-the-difference-between-these-commands-for-bringing-down-a-linux-server/196014#196014). It focuses on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, but as RHEL is using systemd just as Debian does, the explanations made there should be applicable to Debian as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's reasonable in the sense that `reboot` ends up calling `shutdown` afterwards anyway (unless you `--force` it), but unless you're working on some omega obsolete system, it's highly unlikely you will ever experience any performance impact from this.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot